# Stop / Play Button in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer, android-button

I am developing an app and I have one button for play and stop. The buttons work perfectly, but when I play music, go into the background to some other app, then return to my app, my play/stop button is starting to play again if I press it. This is a problem because I need to press the play button again (although the music is playing) and then press the stop button. Any ideas? My code is:

```
boolean isOn = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if(isOn) {
   stopService(new Intent(this, ServisZaStream.class));
      isOn = false;

 }else{
  startService(new Intent(this, ServisZaStream.class));
     isOn = true;
  }


    });

  }  
}
```

Comment: your app forgets the state of your boolean whenever you put your app in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your isOn flag in Bundle when your app is stopped or paused:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putBoolean("EXTRA_IS_ON", isOn);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and then retrieve it in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isOn = savedInstance.getBoolean("EXTRA_IS_ON");
    }
}
```

Comment: outState.putString("EXTRA_IS_ON", isOn); ERROR: 
The method putString(String, String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)

Comment: @user2528081 sorry, the correct method is **putBoolean("EXSTRA_IS_ON", isOn)**;

Answer (score 3):

You need a way to get the current state of your background service from your app, and set the state of your button accordingly upon resuming your app.

This is part of the Android app life-cycle.  Anything not persisted into a bundle could be lost when the activity is sent to the background.  So you need to retrieve any state you are interested in when the app is resumed.

Android functions this way to save memory and CPU.

Comment: Thanks ,I understand what are you talking about I am young developer I am still learning ,Do you have any example or link ?

Answer (score 0):

your app forget the value of boolean so u need to do it with the help of such a mechanism that it does not forget boolean value.. i usually do it with the singleton class.. you can find any way for your application or you can do it with the help of singleton  as well...